# datetime range vb.net for loop

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, datetime

I have 2 DateTime values in a VB.NET application.

Dim startDate as DateTime
Dim endDate as DateTime

Now i want to make a loop for each day between startDate and endDate like:

For Each day As Integer In ??????????

Next

someone have an idea?

Comment: If you found your own solution to the problem, then please post that as an answer and accept it as the correct answer (you won't receive any rep for this so this is fine to do). That way other people can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 2):

**C#**:

```
for(DateTime CurrentDate = StartDate; 
    CurrentDate < EndDate; 
    CurrentDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(1))
{
}
```

**VB.NET**:

```
Dim CurrentDate As DateTime = StartDate
While CurrentDate < EndDate
    CurrentDate = CurrentDate.AddDays(1)
End While
```

Comment: Oops... I automatically answered in C#.

Comment: thanks this works, but i got a better method, for peaple searching the solution, take a look at the TimeSpan object. thanks anyway

Comment: @Vincent: it would be nice for people searching the solution if you would have edited your question to add this solution. Btw, Timespan does not contain dates but only the duration between dates. So i don't see a way how you want to get the dates betweeen startdate and enddate from a timespan!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim currentDate As Date = startDate 
While currentDate <= endDate
    'do something with this date...'
    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
End While
```

Comment: wow thanks for the anwsers, i already found some else what is the best solution: